# What are the benefits of using separate hosts for read and write in mysql (laravel)?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

As [laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#read-and-write-connections) says:

> Sometimes you may wish to use one database connection for SELECT statements, and another for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements. Laravel makes this a breeze, and the proper connections will always be used whether you are using raw queries, the query builder, or the Eloquent ORM.

What is the **benefit** of doing this and what are the **tradeoffs**?

Comment: This would be for security purposes

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez Actually, no. Adding more SQL servers will increase the attack surface towards the stored data (at least in respect to reading, which is often the primary goal of attacks) and will therefore not improve security.

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez: actually, you are partially right. If you don't even open a write connection if you only need to read from it, there is a slight security improvement after all.

Comment: Read-Write separation is basically Master-Slave architecture. This is a Too Broad question, and will welcome opinionated answers as well; thus it is Off-Topic here at StackOverflow. Duplicate marked question has an answer to your question.

Comment: Another answer here: https://serverfault.com/a/350219 as well .. and a simple search for "benefit of read write separation" in your favorite search engine, will definitely provide you a plethora of links to get information.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware of, this is normally done if you have a very read-heavy application. In such a case you can have a master-slave database system which performs internal replication in order to provide more hardware power to feed the application. The slave can be a machine optimized for reading while the master is optimized for writing, although I've to admit that this goes far beyond my expertise.

There are also alternatives for load balancing SQL connections, for example [using HAProxy](https://severalnines.com/resources/tutorials/mysql-load-balancing-haproxy-tutorial).